How can I efficiently manage multiple 'LiveData' sources in a 'ViewModel'?
I’m struggling to handle updates from multiple 'LiveData' sources in my 'ViewModel'. Specifically, I have several 'LiveData' objects representing different aspects of my UI’s state, such as user profile information, notifications, and app settings. I need to combine these sources and ensure that updates are handled efficiently without causing unnecessary 'recompositions' or performance issues. How can I manage these sources in a way that maintains a responsive UI and avoids redundant data processing?
I attempted to use 'MediatorLiveData' to combine updates from the various 'LiveData' sources and observed them in the 'ViewModel'. I expected that this would allow me to control when and how updates are propagated to the UI. However, I am still seeing performance issues, and the UI updates are not as efficient as I hoped. I tried different strategies, including manually combining LiveData and using transformation functions, but these approaches haven’t resolved the issue completely.

This question is way to broad. You'd be more likely to get a coherent answer if you focus on a simple example
